# Use Conditional Formatting on a Cell Based on matching a value in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to change the cell background of a cell (M16) if the number in it matches one of the numbers in a table of random numbers (M3:Q12)

Table of numbers - M3:Q12     Cell I want to format is M16.

How do I make the cell background M16 red if the number in it matches any value in the table of numbers. The number in cell M16 may appear in the table of numbers (M3:Q12) more than once.

I then want to expand this formatting to the range of M16:Q40 so if a number is ever entered in the table m16:Q40 and matches a number in the other table (M3:Q12) the cell background turns red.

I've exceeded my Excel knowledge and can't figure out how to easily do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Under Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format:

A rule to fill only M16 is `=COUNTIFS(M3:Q12,M16)>0` applied to **=M16**.

A rule to fill the range M16:Q40 is `=COUNTIFS($M$3:$Q$12,M16)>0` applied to **=$M$16:$Q$40**.